# format cell values to phone number format

Tags: excel, vba

I have phone numbers listed in Column A of Sheet1. Currently they dont have any format and are stored as: 1112223333

I want to convert them to: 111.222.3333

I tried:

```
Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, "###.###.####")
```

which gives me "1112223333.."

EDIT:
When I try to format it to:

```
Format(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value, "(###) ###-####")
```

It works perfectly fine: (111) 222-3333

Its just with the "111.222.3333" format that I am having issues with. Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The periods need to be converted to text, otherwise they're read as decimal points:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "###"".""###"".""####"
```